# Remove from list with Python list comprehension

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

Why isn't the number 4 removed from the following list?

```
>>> list=[1,2,3,4]
>>> [list.remove(item) for item in list if item > 2]
[None]
>>> list
[1, 2, 4]
```

Also, what I'm trying to do is remove items from `listA` if item found in `listB`. How can I do this with list a comprehension?

Also, how would I do:

```
list2=["prefix1","prefix2"]
[item for item in list if not "item starts with a prefix in list2"] # pseudocode
```

Comment: Because deleting elements of the object when you are iterating over it makes the index to move, skipping the next value. So here is never evaluated. That's why it is important to make a copy before a loop and then replace the object.

Comment: What's `items` anyway?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove items from a list while iterating in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207406/remove-items-from-a-list-while-iterating-in-python)

Answer (score 4):

First of all, using a list comprehension only for its side effects is a bad practice. You should use

```
lst = [x for x in lst if x <= 2]
```

Additionally, don't use `list` as a variable name, because it is already taken by the builtin list. Third of all, your approach is not working because you are iterating over your list while mutating it.

Here's a demo of what's happening with your approach:

```
# python interpreter
>>> lst = [1,2,3,4]
>>> for item in lst:
...     print(item)
...     if item > 2:
...         lst.remove(item)
...     print(lst)
... 
1
[1, 2, 3, 4]
2
[1, 2, 3, 4]
3
[1, 2, 4]
```

As you can see, `item` is never `4`.

As for your second question:

> Also, what I'm trying to do is remove items from `listA` if item found in `listB`. How can I do this with list comprehension?

```
bset = set(listB)
listA = [x for x in listA if x not in bset]
```

As for your third question:

```
>>> list1=['prefix1hello', 'foo', 'prefix2hello', 'hello']
>>> prefixes=['prefix1', 'prefix2']
>>> [x for x in list1 if not any(x.startswith(prefix) for prefix in prefixes)]
['foo', 'hello']
```

Please stop adding new questions now, you can open a new question for a different problem, thanks.

Comment: Perfect man! I updated my post a little, can you see if the second problem can be done using list comprehension?

Comment: Perhaps `lst[:] = [x for x in lst if x <= 2]` would be subtly better.

Comment: ummm... is there a way to break up those two list comprehension into two lines to make it a little prettier?

Comment: @user3388884 you could just use a traditional for loop if you don't like the comprehension.

Comment: @kojiro mutating `lst` seems to be slower. I'd only use `lst[:]` if I really wanted to mutate `lst` for some reason.